# why is django/sqlite barfing on my parameterized raw() query?

Tags: regex, django, sqlite

i'm not sure whether my issue is django, sqlite3, some odd interaction with regexp syntax, or just me:  i've got a BAD version of a SQL query to be handled correctly by django.model:

```
qryStrBAD = "SELECT idx, cdate, beat FROM app_database where cc  regexp '^%s'" % (cc)
for c in MyModel.objects.raw(qryStrBAD):
```

this works.  but of course i don't want to allow injection attacks, so i've swapped it to the recommended params list version of `raw()`:

```
qryStr = "SELECT idx, cdate, beat FROM app_database where cc regexp '^%s'"
for c in MyModel.objects.raw(qryStr,[cc]):
```

but using this throws

```
DatabaseError at <URL>
Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 0, and there are 1 supplied
```

even odder is that poking thru the traceback log seems to show that the substition is being done correctly:

```
** .../app/views.py in plotResults

        for c in MyModel.objects.raw(qryStr,[cc]):

    ...

Local vars

qryStr:     "SELECT idx, cdate, beat FROM app_database where cc regexp '^%s'"
cc:             u'LARCENY_THEFT'

** /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py in __iter__
<RawQuerySet: u"SELECT idx, cdate, beat FROM app_database where cc regexp '^LARCENY_THEFT'">


** /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py in _execute_query
<RawQuery: u"SELECT idx, cdate, beat FROM app_database where cc regexp '^LARCENY_THEFT'">

** /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py in execute
Local vars

params:     [u'LARCENY_THEFT']
sql:            u"SELECT idx, cdate, beat FROM app_database where cc regexp '^LARCENY_THEFT'"


** /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py in execute

                six.reraise(utils.DatabaseError, utils.DatabaseError(*tuple(e.args)), sys.exc_info()[2])

    ...


ProgrammingError('Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 0, and there are 1 supplied.',)
Local vars


params:     [u'LARCENY_THEFT']
query:          u"SELECT idx, cdate, beat FROM app_database where cc regexp '^?'"

** /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py in execute
Local vars

params:     [u'LARCENY_THEFT']
query:          u"SELECT idx, cdate, beat FROM app_database where cc regexp '^?'"
```

any guesses what's up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't try to combine `^` with your parameter inside the querystring.

Instead, create the regular expression separately, then use it as a parameter.

```
startswith_cc = '^%s' % startswith_cc
qryStr = "SELECT idx, cdate, beat FROM app_database where cc regexp %s"
for c in MyModel.objects.raw(qryStr, [startswith_cc]):
    ...
```

Comment: i think you meant `startswith_cc = '"^%s"' % cc` ? (we need extra quotes for the regexp, and the original variable was `cc`.)    then i thought i liked your basic idea, but it doesn't work: this matches zero records (:

Comment: wait: WITHOUT the extra quotes this does work!?!  any chance you can help me rationalize why the `^` is a special issue, just how python/sqlite/sql parsers are dividing this substitution process up?  in any case, you solved my bug, thanks Alasdair!

Comment: I believe the python sqlite3 module takes care of escaping the stings. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005552/sqlite-parameter-substitution-and-quotes or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105249/python-sqlite-parameter-substitution-with-wildcards-in-like.