# SQL query in python script, how to get quotes around a parameter?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I need to rewrite the php script that handles a POST request and queries a SQLite3 database into python. The Query now looks like this

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * from "+requestedProgram+" WHERE start LIKE ? ORDER BY start", (requestedDate,))
```

the first part until the *WHERE* condition works (it is not elegant but unfortunately it seems that table names cannot be parametrized).

However, I need to put quotes around the requestedDate string in order to make *LIKE* work. How do I get quotes around the parameter/variable?

On another note: does the *ORDER BY* statement even do anything considering the nature of the cursor?

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes, don't use the trailing comma behind requestedDate (it tuple-izes it), and add a trailing wildcard to the string.

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * from "+requestedProgram+" WHERE start LIKE '?' ORDER BY start", requestedDate + '%')
```

Edit: Updated per conversation thread with OP below. Details added for those who stumble across this.

Comment: I tried that, however I get the error `sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 0, and there are 1 supplied.` when doing that, the same as when using regular quotes implying the _?_ isn't recognized as a parameter.

Comment: Use `%s` instead of `?`.

Comment: `sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error`

Is the new error I get.

Comment: My bad. I was looking at MySQLCursor. Here's the documentation on sqlite cursor: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html

Comment: Yeah I had found that doc. I was using the python3 version https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/sqlite3.html using _?_ since that is what I originally used. I tried running it with %s and python2 yielding the above syntax error

Comment: According to their example `c.execute('SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE symbol=?', t)` the above should work. You just need to remove the parens and comma from around your variable.

Comment: The example apparently is a single element. If I omit the parens and comma, it interprets every character of the string as an individual element of the parameter tuple and throws this error `sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 7 supplied.
`

Comment: Ah, try using `str(requestedDate)`

Comment: I am not familiar with str(), when I use the function either in the tuple or when setting the variable I get `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`
/ EDIT: Now I am thoroughly confused. I still get this error even after taking out str()

Comment: Have you declared a variable called `str`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039605/typeerror-str-object-is-not-callable-python

Comment: No, I hadn't before and now "str" is completely gone from my code, still getting this error https://i.imgur.com/VP7QBP9.png

Pretty fascinating ;) Is something about my setting variables wrong? I am a python newbie so I don't know if I need a dict or something there.

Comment: :O type `vi programlookup.py` and see if the contents match what's in your editor.

Comment: They do. I am going to restart this machine real quick, that should get rid of it. EDIT: It didn't, still getting the same error

Comment: It's cool - I think I figured it out! When I used `cursor.execute("SELECT ... " (requestedDate,))` I got the same error, then I changed it to `cursor.execute("SELECT ...", str(requestedDate))` and it worked.

Comment: the error as you have just shown me was that I had forgotten the comma between query and tuple :D I am a bit stupid. now both `(requestedDate,)` and `(str(requestedDate),)` "work" in that they at least return an empty query result. Something about the like condition is still a problem but that's another issue. Thanks so far! EDIT: wait, no, that's pretty much what I had in the beginning... :D

Comment: Nice! Try `LIKE '\%?\%'` for your where clause. Also, what type and format is the `start` field?

Comment: Hm, that causes it to not recognize the _?_ binding at all anymore. Start is a string in the form of "20140706071500 +0200" for example and with `LIKE '20140701'` I want to check for entries from july 1st 2014. This works in the PHP solution `SELECT * from $Program WHERE start LIKE '$Date' ORDER BY start;   `

Comment: Oh God nevermind I just forgot to get a % behind the string used in like which was my only mistake from the beginning -.-

Comment: Gotcha... try `"...LIKE '?' ORDER BY start", str(requestedDate) + '%')` per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105249/python-sqlite-parameter-substitution-with-wildcards-in-like  If the value of `start` will always begin with the datestamp, you should use something that results in `LIKE '20140701%'`.

Comment: Yeah I did something like that. I'll leave the str() away though since it is a proper string and it works thanks through the tupelization by the comma. Thanks again ;)