# How do you SELECT all rows of an sqlite3 database that have a column that contains a certain variable substring?

Tags: python, sqlite

I know how to use the LIKE clause to extract rows that have a column that contains a hard-coded substring:

```
SELECT * FROM userTable WHERE UPPER(column) LIKE UPPER('%this_is_a_hard_coded_string%')
```

But I can't figure out how to use a variable for the substring instead of a hardcoded substring. Usually, when I make an sqlite3 query with python3, I can set a value equal to a ? and then add an extra argument to the execute method on the cursor; however, that does not seem to work here.

Comment: There is another potentially bigger problem here.  The pattern `LIKE %substring%` will fire true for _any_ string which has that `substring`, even if the substring is just a fragment of a larger word.  You should try to use full text search if possible, it's worth your investment of time.

Comment: What's full text search? Also, why is it bad to fire true even when a substring is just a fragment of a larger word.

Comment: Read here: https://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html

Comment: Oh, I see. Using LIKE is really inefficient.

Comment: Right tool for the right job.  There is an overhead to a full text index, and it can be large, and maybe on a mobile device you don't want that.  Hopefully you can make a better decision now.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: But if I did want to use the LIKE command with a variable, how would I go about it? (note: not playing on it; just out of curiosity.)

Comment: See here for how to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105249/python-sqlite-parameter-substitution-with-wildcards-in-like?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
t = ("%"+"this_is_a_hard_coded_string"+"%",)
c.execute('SELECT * FROM userTable WHERE UPPER(column) LIKE UPPER(?)', t)
```

You can also use a different more readable use of "?".

Refer this  answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1010804/1471352

or this

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3105370/1471352

Comment: Yes, this works. Thanks. This answer was already written in the comments though.