# Using LIKE in sqlite3 with more than one condition

Tags: python, sqlite

I am using python 2.7 and trying to use LIKE method with sqlite3

```
search1 = self.lineEdit.text()
search = unicode(search1)
conn = sqlite3.connect('storage/container.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT * FROM reports WHERE LIKE('؟%',outIn)=1 OR LIKE('؟%',itemName)=1 OR LIKE('؟%',itemUser)=1", (search, search, search, ))
```

gives me an error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python\townoftechwarehouse\reports.py", line 67, in create_report
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM reports WHERE LIKE('؟%',outIn)=1 OR LIKE('؟%',itemName)=1 OR LIKE('؟%',itemUser)=1", (search, search, search, ))
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 0, and there are 3 supplied.
[Finished in 18.2s]
```

Comment: "؟" is not "?".

Comment: The answer is already provided here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105249/python-sqlite-parameter-substitution-with-wildcards-in-like)

Answer (score 0):

[As documented here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html), the correct placeholder for sqlite3 is '?', not '%s'.