# How to implement a search function using a raw SQL query

Tags: python, sql, flask, sqlalchemy, jinja2

I am creating an app guided by CS50's web series, which requires me to ONLY use raw SQL queries not ORM.

I am trying to make a search function where a user can look up the list of books that's stored in the database. I want to able them to query ISBN, title, author column in the table called 'books'

Currently, it does shoot a 'GET' request with no problem but it is not returning any data and I think the problem is at the SQL line I've scripted.

Here's the route:

```py
@app.route("/", methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
    # search function for books
    if request.method == "GET":
        searchQuery = request.form.get("searchQuery")
        # return value from the search
        searchResult = db.execute("SELECT isbn, author, title FROM books WHERE isbn LIKE '%"+searchQuery+"%' OR author LIKE '%"+searchQuery+"%' OR title LIKE '%"+searchQuery+"%'").fetchall()
        # add search result to the list
        session["books"] = []
        # add the each result to the list
        for i in searchResult:
            session["books"].append(i)
        return render_template("index.html", books=session["books"])
    return render_template("index.html")
```

and here's my template.

```html
    <form method="GET">
        <input type="text" name="searchQuery" class="searchTerm" placeholder="What are you looking for?">
        <button type="submit" class="searchButton">submit</button>
    </form>
    <div>
        <h3>
            {% for book in books %}
            {{ book }}
            {% endfor %}
        </h3>
    </div>
```

Can anyone spot the problem, please? Please note that I am supposed to utilize the raw SQL queries and session.

Comment: Are you using SQLite? where did you open db and cursor object? What happens when you print the `searchResult` ?

Comment: shorter `session["books"] = searchResult`. Or even shorter `books=searchResult`

Comment: print query on screen and use it directly in database (using any DB viewer/editor) to see if you get any results for this query. You can also check `len(searchResult)`

Comment: @furas when you say DB editor, like in Adminer?

Comment: yes, it can be Adminer, or [DBbeaver](https://dbeaver.io/), [HeidiSQL](https://www.heidisql.com/), etc. But every database have also preinstalled program to access it in console/terminal/cmd.exe. MySQL has program `mysql`, SQLite has program `sqlite3`, etc. so you don't have to install external programs but they work in text mode so they are not so user friendly like GUI programs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a github with full solution for you :)

https://github.com/researcher2/stackoverflow_57120430

A couple of things:

**Avoiding SQL Injection**

I recommend using bindings when doing raw sql statements, my code reflects that. I spent ages trying to get this working with your statement before stumbling upon this:

[Python SQLite parameter substitution with wildcards in LIKE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105249/python-sqlite-parameter-substitution-with-wildcards-in-like)

Basically you can't put bindings inside the LIKE '%?%' because the quotes cause the replacement token to be ignored.

Instead you just have to do LIKE ? and build the replacement manually.

**Using Session**

All session information is JSON serialized and then sent to the client. In this case the row records weren't JSON serializable. This showed up as an error for me:

```
TypeError: Object of type 'RowProxy' is not JSON serializable
```

I probably wouldn't use the session here as there is no need for the client to be aware of this, as you're going to build them a nice html page with the information anyway. Just use a python dictionary and pass it to the template engine. My code did use the session because this is what you started with.

In case github ever goes down:

```
from flask import request, render_template, session
from app import app, db

@app.route("/", methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == "POST":
        searchQuery = request.form.get("searchQuery")
        print(searchQuery)

        # Avoid SQL Injection Using Bindings
        sql = "SELECT isbn, author, title \
               FROM book \
               WHERE isbn LIKE :x \
               OR author LIKE :y \
               OR title LIKE :z"

        # I spent an hour wondering why I couldnt put the bindings inside the wildcard string...
        # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105249/python-sqlite-parameter-substitution-with-wildcards-in-like
        matchString = "%{}%".format(searchQuery)

        stmt = db.text(sql).bindparams(x=matchString, y=matchString, z=matchString)

        results = db.session.execute(stmt).fetchall()
        print(results)

        session["books"] = []

        for row in results:
            # A row is not JSON serializable so we pull out the pieces
            book = dict()
            book["isbn"] = row[0]
            book["author"] = row[1]
            book["title"] = row[2]
            session["books"].append(book)
        return render_template("index.html", searchedFor=searchQuery, books=session["books"])

    return render_template("index.html")
```

Comment: you went above and beyond for the question i had. thanks so much. I honestly do not understand %100 of it but it's going to be a fantastic studying material.

Comment: You're welcome, would you believe I find this fun. Let me know if you have any questions about the repo. I would imagine you haven't seen requirements file and the sqlalchemy orm stuff yet?

Comment: `book = dict(row)` would suffice for the serialization.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the chosen answer.
The problem was solved with one simple change.

I needed to swap 'LIKE' to 'ILIKE' in the SQL query line.

```py
searchResult = db.execute(
    """
    SELECT isbn, author, title
    FROM books
    WHERE isbn ILIKE :search OR author ILIKE :search OR title ILIKE :search
    """,
    {"search": "%"+searchQuery+"%"}
).fetchall()
```

This may not be an elegant solution but it did solve a temporary problem. Again, kudos for the guy who answered and create a github repo for everyone else who would encounter the problem while doing CS50's web series!

Comment: Nice work. Did I misread and you aren't using flask sessions, just a variable called session?

Comment: @Researcher I am actually using it. `from flask import session`